# Android - back button from a send-intent closes application

Tags: android-intent, sharing

i have a drawer menu, when i press one of its buttons to start a sharing intent as below:

```
Intent iFriends = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
iFriends.setType("text/plain");
iFriends.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.liveplus.mobi");
iFriends.createChooser(iFriends, "Invite Friends");
startActivity(iFriends);
```

The sharing dialog appears, but if i press the back button, the whole application exits!

any idea!